# Remove duplicate Barcode no. and sumup the quantity

Tags: sql-server

I want to delete duplicate Barcode No. and then sum the quantity for the same.

```
Barcode No 1,2,1,2,1
Quantity : 10,10,10,20,10
```

I want result as :

```
Barcode No 1,2
Quantity : 30, 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your column_name `Barcode No` is having spaces; you have to include those in square brackets if you wanna show output in required format.

In SQL Server square brackets are used to enclose object names that contain spaces, special characters or reserved words.

To Sum up quantity per bar code, you can use `SUM()` and `group by`

```
SELECT [Barcode No], SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM table_name
GROUP BY [Barcode No];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  SELECT
   Barcode, SUM(Quantity) as Quantity
  FROM
    <table name>
  GROUP BY
    Barcode;
```

You will need to put in the correct table name.